# Automating GCP Dataform Release Configuration Update via CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform

I'm working on setting up a CI/CD pipeline that automatically updates the Release configuration in GCP Dataform by compiling `dataform.json` whenever branches are merged into the main branch on GitHub. I'm encountering an issue where after the automated update, I cannot run executions within Dataform.

The documentation I've referenced includes:

- [Release configurations in Dataform](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/release-configurations)
- [Compilation overrides in Dataform](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/compilation-overrides)
- [CompilationResult REST Resource](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.repositories.compilationResults#CompilationResult)

Using the following `curl` command, I successfully create a new compilation result:

```bash
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/my-project/locations/us-west1/repositories/my-repo/compilationResults" \
--data '{
  "gitCommitish": "main",
}'
```

This command correctly informs me of the new compilation result name. I then use this output to patch my Release:

```bash
curl -X PATCH \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{
  "gitCommitish": "main",
  "releaseCompilationResult": "projects/my-project/locations/us-west1/repositories/my-repo/compilationResults/{{ NEW COMPILATION RESULT ID }}"
}'  \
"https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/my-project/locations/us-west1/repositories/my-repo/releaseConfigs/my-release-config"
```

While this process does update the target Release Config, I can no longer initiate runs in Dataform; the UI button for running actions becomes non-responsive. However, if I manually generate a new compilation, everything returns to normal, and I'm able to run executions again.

Here are my questions:

1. What additional steps are required to ensure the Release config update allows for normal execution runs?
2. Is there a specific part of the automated update process that differs from the manual process, which could be causing this issue?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!